# webpage not match html

Tags: html, dreamhost

I have a webpage where I have the following element ( view source via browser ):

```
<p>Phone: (919) YYY-ZZZZ</p>
```

but for some reason a different phone number is being displayed visually.  Why is that?

Important note: viewing source shows the correct phone number, the problem is what is actually displayed.  Could "view source" be bringing up some other webpage?  If I were looking at the HTML on the server, I would just assume it has not been published yet, but since I am using "view source" in the browser, that cannot be it in this case.  Any ideas?

Comment: “View source” shows the source HTML, not the serialized DOM after any DOM manipulation. Try selecting the element and showing the “selection source”.

Comment: Ok, that helped.  Must be one of the JavaScript files changing it, since I definitely see in the "selection source" what I see on the screen.